# How do I get a date with months in words with the following javascript code:

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have this Javascript code:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}

today = dd+'/'+mm;
document.write(today);
```

Now the months are in mm, so mumbers, I want them to display in words. Now I am not a javescript genius, actually a noob, but my logical mind thought of this:

```
if(mm = 1){mm = 'January'}
```

Now as I was already expecting, that doesn't work.

Is there a way to transform the numbers in words with this code, or should I look for another way?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @pax162: is that really necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array or object of month names like this:

```
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
```

Then just get the month you need like this:

```
mm = months[mm - 1];
```

`-1` is because JS is zero-based, so January is at index 0, February at 1, etc.

Also, like GolezTrol said, your approach is fine, you just need to use the comparison operator (==) instead of assignment operator (=) in your if-clause.

Comment: no, you don't need the `-1`. January is 0, February is 1, etc.

Comment: @Doorknob: in the question `mm` was defined as `new Date().getMonth() + 1`, so technically this is correct - though there's no _real_ point in doing something which is redundant.

Comment: @Doorknob, yes but, in the question it says if mm == 1, mm is January.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Hm, it was, but why add one and then subtract one? Just keep the original value...

Comment: Judging by all that, it might be a good idea to even go with `(mm - 1) % 12`, just in case...

Comment: Thanks worked, I erased the `+1` in the original code and the `- 1` from your answer and that worked as well.

Comment: Great, glad it helped! Also, to show code in the comments you need to use backtick (`) like this: backtick Your_code_here backtick (no spaces needed).

Answer (score 1):

`if(mm == 1){mm = 'January'}` would work better. The problem is the single `=`, which isn't a comparison operator and should be double `==`. This is the actual error in your code.

You could write it a bit easier/more readable though, by using an array as @Shomz already suggested. Or for other cases like this, a switch might help you out:

```
switch (mm) {
  case 1: return 'January'; break;
  case 2: return 'February'; break;
  case 3: return 'March'; break;
  case 4: return 'April'; break;
  ...
}
```

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/switch.shtml

In this case, though, the array solution is the easiest.